# How to Create Virtual Diectory build asp.net web site using nant?

Tags: asp.net, iis, nant, virtual-directory

I am trying to Create Virtual Directory and develop the asp.net projects ..in IIS using NAnt script .
Would u pls tell me the Solution .

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "mkiisdir" task in NantContrib to create your virtual directory:
[link to mksiidir](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc2/help/tasks/mkiisdir.html).  If you want more fine control, you can use the custom Nant task created by this guy here: [Custom Nant Task](http://www.persistall.com/archive/2007/06/11/nant-task-for-creating-iis-application-mappings.aspx)

-Diego

Comment: Thanks Diego. This task does work, but I did not see a way to set the application pool to something other that the 'default'. Do you know of a way to accomplish this?